# Stripe Integration Issue: 0.00 Amount Displayed at Checkout

Tags: stripe-payments, strip

During the checkout process, when I proceed to the verification page, the payment amount is displayed as 0.00. However, after completing the verification process, Stripe charges the correct amount.
If anyone has experienced a similar issue or has any suggestions for a solution, I would be grateful for your assistance. How can I resolve this problem and ensure that the correct payment amount is displayed throughout the entire checkout process?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement payment intent instead of setup intent.
Then it will be resolved.